# update listView from ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbaractivity

My MainActivity, which extends ActionBarActivity, has a ListView, which I want to reload using `notifyDataSetChanged()`, but I do not know how to do this.

My code so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private JournalEntryDataSource datasource;
    private ListView listView = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        datasource = new JournalEntryDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        List<JournalEntry> values = datasource.getAllJournalEntries();


        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<JournalEntry>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.lugares, values));



        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
                Log.i("app", "Deleting item number " + position);
                datasource.deleteJournalEntry((JournalEntry) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position));

                //I would like to do this here:  
                //ArrayAdapter<JournalEntry> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<JournalEntry>) getListAdapter();
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

            }
        });


    }
```

But I get an error when calling `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`...

Any tips? I've been looking at similar questions and no luck so far...
--------EDITED CODE---------

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        datasource = new JournalEntryDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        values = datasource.getAllJournalEntries();
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<JournalEntry>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.lugares, values));
        ArrayAdapter<JournalEntry> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<JournalEntry>) getListAdapter();
        // use the SimpleCursorAdapter to show the
        // elements in a ListView



        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<JournalEntry>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.lugares, values));
        listView.setLongClickable(true);
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Log.i("hola","borrando la posición "+position);
                JournalEntry removeMe = (JournalEntry)listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                values.remove(removeMe);
                datasource.deleteJournalEntry(removeMe);
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                reloadMe();


                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    public void reloadMe(){
        //need to do this better... but meh.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    protected ListView getListView() {
        if (listView == null) {
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        }
        return listView;
    }

    protected void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    protected ListAdapter getListAdapter() {
        ListAdapter adapter = getListView().getAdapter();
        if (adapter instanceof HeaderViewListAdapter) {
            return ((HeaderViewListAdapter)adapter).getWrappedAdapter();
        } else {
            return adapter;
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated Answer for updated code

instead of creating the same activity again, you should choose to set another new adapter object with the new values object.

```
public void reloadMe(){
        //need to do this better... but meh.
        //Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        //this.startActivity(intent);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<JournalEntry>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.lugares, values));
    }
```

Perhaps, you are deleting from

```
datasource.deleteJournalEntry((JournalEntry) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position));
```

But you did not set "datasource" as the data source of the adapter. If you look carefully you did set the "values" list object-

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<JournalEntry>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.lugares, values));
```

Perhaps you may need to also remove from the values list also.

Comment: this fixed an error calling the method on adapter, but does not reload the list when deleting an entry... it does however delete it correctly from my SQLite db.

Comment: a temporary fix has been, after deleting doing the following:
Intent intent = new Intent(this, this.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);

Comment: please check the updated answer. And kindly accept the answer if this solves your problem . Cheers :)